# How to get python to read a file that has been opened through File Explorer?

Tags: python, file

I don't exactly know how to phrase this question, but I have tried my best.

Let's say I have an application and I have set it to be the default to run when the *.example* file extention has been double clicked within File Explorer. Now, how do I get this application not to just launch, but instead to react as if it has been asked to open the file. Now I know there is the: 

`file = open ("C:\\ExampleFolder\\ExampleFile.example)`
`file = file.read()`


method of reading a file but how would I get the program to run this script when the program is launched by the opening of a file and in which way would I get the program to know the location of the opened file? I know that there are questions about setting a python app to the default but I have found nothing, if I am asking the question right, on completing the above on stackoverflow or a Google search. Or I am just looking at this wrong or asking the question wrong?

Comment: When you double click on a file (at least in windows) it puts the filepath as the first parameter in the command line arguments.

Comment: Generally you can associate an extension with an application by modifying Windows registry. This can also be done for a Python script by associating a "python.exe yourscript.py $1" shell command with it. In your script it will appear like it was passed the filename and path as an argument -- so it will be in `sys.arg[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this might be what you are looking for. You can check whether, double clicking on a file with extension .example which you have linked to your program, means that an argument is passed to your program: the file name being opened. You can check whether this is the case by:

```
import sys

print sys.argv
#if that is meaningless, try printing every single argument passed to the script
#I can't recall whether len(sys.argv) is also = sys.argc!
for x in xrange(len(sys.argv)):
    print sys.argv[x]
```

I hope this is of some help!